# Merge diff corrupts code in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, diff

I am trying to merge some revisions in IntelliJ and it showed a diff for me. Unfortunately, diff does not notice identical code and inserts strange text like

```
<<<<<<<HEAD
```

into result.

Here is screenshot. As you see, code is identical, but it is colored somewhere red and somewhere blue.

[image]

How to restore normal merge functionality?

Comment: actually its not a strange text, it shows your current code in a place of conflict when you try to merge with another commit. It 'll be more clear if you can screen shot and put the full file. :))

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a merge conflict. You can read here for more information about how IntelliJ handles conflicts under Conflict Resolution Tool here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/resolving-conflicts.html

The "strange text" is injected into the conflicted file by Git, so you would see these even outside the IntelliJ merge tool.  If the local and remote content differs, a line of `=` signs will be the divider between your local version and the remote version. In this case since both revisions are equal, you simply have a single line conflict with the same content from both sources.

Essentially, you need to choose which revision of the code to use by selecting the chevrons & X's on either side of the window panel of your screenshot. There is also a handy 'merge non-conflicting changes' button that makes reviewing the actual conflicts much easier.

Comment: Why is it displaying conflict this way? I had a lot of conflicts previously, and they were displayed different way. I was able to choose either left or right or both. No any text was injected.

Comment: Look at your own Jetbrains link. It has conflict too. Both sides are red, which means conflict. At any side I can press either ">>" or "x". I can press "x" at both sides and I can press ">>" at both sides too. And there is no any ">>>>>>>>>>>>>" in result text. This is how it was behaving all the time previously.